# selection exect matching record from a transtion table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello all i have a table which have two columns `trial_id` , `category_id`

I am attaching the image so that it become more clear.

When I want the records of `trial_id` which have `category_id` i can run a query like

```
 SELECT * FROM `trial_category` WHERE category_id IN ( 259, 260 )
```

You can se it give `trial_id` associate with these two `category_id`

My problem is that now I want the `trial_id` which have exact match with these two `category_id` how can i do?

Means if you notic only `trial_id` 73 have both 259 and 260 `category_id` then my result should be only 73.

Thanks[image]

Comment: GROUP BY... HAVING COUNT(*) = count of items in IN()

Comment: Thanks , Can you please give me that mysql query.

Comment: No. I'm sure someone else will oblige, but I think it's important to take some steps by yourself

Comment: what about WHERE category_id=259 and category_id=260;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  Here is a solution using `group by` with the `having` clause:

```
SELECT trial_id
FROM trial_category
group by trial_id
having sum(case when category_id = 259 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when category_id = 260 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is satisfied when one of the rows has the specific category.  You can see how this easily generalizes to more categories.  Or even to the case 259 but not 260 and 261.

If you want *exactly* these two categories, you can filter on rows that do not have any other categories by adding this clause:

```
       sum(case when category_id not in (259, 260) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

IN ( 259, 260 )

Comment: Thanks, In your second solution (if you want exactly these two categories, you can filter on rows that do not have any other categories by adding this clause:) , if I have only one category_id let say (259) then output should be only 213 , but it is not showing, Can you please give me some more help.

Comment: If I query for category_id 259 then it shows only trial_id 213 not all trail id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT trial_id, count(trial_id) AS ccnt
FROM trial_category
WHERE category_id IN ( 259,260)
GROUP BY trial_id
HAVING ccnt = 2
```

Comment: count(*) probably must be more than one `>1`, maybe there more than 2  same category_id per trial_id.

Comment: He only mentions two categories hence the 2.

Comment: If I query for category_id 259 then it shows only trial_id 213 not all trail id.

Answer (score 1):

Use group by clause:

```
SELECT trail_id FROM `trial_category` 
WHERE category_id IN ( 259, 260 ) 
GROUP BY trial_id
HAVING count(trial_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` for `trial_id`

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT *,COUNT(trial_id) as tcount FROM trial_category 
WHERE category_id IN ( 259, 260 ) GRUOP BY trial_id ) q
WHERE q.tcount >1
```

OR

```
SELECT *,COUNT(trial_id) as tcount FROM trial_category 
WHERE category_id IN ( 259, 260 ) GRUOP BY trial_id  HAVING tcount >1
```

Comment: This will still give the trail_id if it only matches one category_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT DISTINCT trail_id FROM `trail_category` WHERE category_id IN ( 259, 260 );
```

Comment: This will still give the trail_id if it only matches one category_id

Comment: I think this might not be the answer to his question. Even if 73 matches one category_id it will show in the result.